# Virtual host not displaying correct files

Tags: apache, centos7, vhosts

Centos 7.1 and apache 2.4 - We have installed a new drive in our server and want to move all of our sites to that drive (mounted as /data) and sites are located in /data/vhosts

When trying to access the site we are presented with the apache welcome screen. I can confirm that the vhost is loaded as trying changing the permissions of the dir above results in a forbidden access. There is also an index.php file located in /data/vhosts/test.mydomain.com/public_html

```
# IP has been changed for example:
 <VirtualHost 91.91.91.91:80>
     DocumentRoot "/data/vhosts/test.mydomain.com/public_html"
     ServerName test.mydomain.com

     <Directory /data/vhosts/test.mydomain.com>
          Options All
          AllowOverride All
          order allow,deny
          allow from all
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I have deleted the welcome.conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ and I am not given a forbidden 403. It is important to note that this is a new drive and no permissions has been set on /data (or sub folders) for apache. I am not entirely sure if that makes a difference?

I have also made some slight alternations to the vhost conf file but no difference:

```
 NameVirtualHost *:80

 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "/data/vhosts/test.mydomain.com/public_html"
     ServerName test.mydomain.com

     <Directory "/data/vhosts/test.mydomain.com">
          AllowOverride None
          # Allow open access:
          Require all granted
      </Directory>


      <Directory /data/vhosts/test.mydomain.com/public_html>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
          DirectoryIndex index.php
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
      </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: the config above looks good.  Have you done an httpd restart?

Comment: I have. I also deleted the welcome.conf file and now it's returning a forbidden 403 - I suspect it may be permissions as the new drive was not setup with any permissions for apache. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the "User" and "Group" settings in httpd.conf.   Usually they are something like "apache" user and "apache" group.  Use these values for a recursive chown (change owner) command on the new drive, ``chown -R apache.apache /data/vhosts``